# Android Eclipse- how to add a youtube video

Tags: android

I want to add a youtube video to my page. I downloaded the video and added it into the res-> raw folder. The video is marked minecraft_trailer.mp4. I am getting an error in the javascript page and I cant figure out what it is. Please help.

```
package com.treacheryofimages.www;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class OtherActivity7 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other7);
    }

    VideoView vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
    R.raw.minecraft_trailer;
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(minecraft_trailer));
    vv.start();
  }
}
```

The error is coming from the vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(minecraft_trailer)); line

I cant tell what it is. Its possibly whats inside the ().
Also, what is supposed to go inside those ()

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong variable `minecraft_trailer` when calling `vv.setVideoURI();`

it should be `vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName ));`

Comment: what goes in the file name

Comment: It is already initializes with the video URI `String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.minecraft_trailer;`

Answer (score 0):

check this out :

```
VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.video);

mc = new MediaController(this);
vd.setMediaController(mc);

vd.setVideoURI(uri);
vd.start();
```